# ngtools2.ts file missing in Angular 9.0.x

Tags: angular, angular9

A clear and concise description of the problem...
ngTools2 file is missing from angular/compiler-cli package Has the file been moved?

```
Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngtools2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was removed. You can check it at github repo.

I am not sure that it is good idea to import stuff this way. It looks like private API. You have `compiler/cli` and it has `index.ts` Exports are public API there. You shouldn't watch how Angular works internally and use something private. It is not flexible at all. You project might be ruined on updates.

Here is the link:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.x/packages/compiler-cli/ngtools2.ts

No such file in 9.x.x:

[image]